# Chapter titles or numbers?

Tags: creative-writing, novel, technique

I am about to start writing a science-fiction novel, and having only ever written technical documents before, I have very little experience in the finer details of creative writing. In particular, I was wondering Do chapters always need a title or is acceptable to have Chapter 1, Chapter 2, etc... with no title?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. These are both good questions, but they're not related. Can you separate them so we can answer each one individually?

Comment: Thank you. I did wonder about separating these in two questions. As they were sort of related, I thought it was OK to put them both in the same question. I'll edit the question now.

Comment: Lauren Ipsum said it. Numbers alone for continuity, names for discreteness. Decide according to organizing the thought flow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chapters don't need to have a title. "Chapter NN" is fine.

Or you can have *only* a title — that's generally when the title identifies some kind of shift, like a different time, location, or narrator/POV focus.

So you can have

> Chapter 1
>
> Chapter 6
>
> Chapter 47

or

Location:

> Vulcan, 2265

POV:

> Brienne

Time:

> A few hours later

Comment: Aw heck, nice. I love this.